# How to fix the height of the md-card inside md-grid-list in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-directives, angular-material2

I am using `"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.2"` version. To display tiles, I have used `md-card` inside `md-grid-list`. I have added the attribute `rowHeight` to the `md-grid-list`. Even though the `rowHeight` is defined, the cards in the row are of not the same height. What attribute I need to use with the `md-card` to have the same height for all the cards in the row?

```
<md-grid-list cols="4"  rowHeight="250px" gutterSize="20px">
  <md-grid-tile  *ngFor="let data of myData">
      <md-card [style.background]="'lightblue'">    
    <md-card-title></md-card-title>
    <md-card-title></md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>
    <h2>    
    </h2>
    </md-card-content>  
    </md-card>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **100%** `minHeight` attributes on your `md-card` to adjust the height only and set `minwidth` also to fill the `md-grid-tile`

Like:

```
[style.minHeight]="'100%'" [style.minWidth]="'100%'"
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1ZsUJ9khTDPG6eU0Z8oU?p=preview) for example.

Comment: @user1731770: may you accept this as answer. if helped you. :)